# How can I make a Label scroll automatically in Xamarin.ios (C#, Xaml)

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.ios, label

Her's my problem I have a Label (metroLabel) included in a BoxView (BoxLabel), who can display a lot of information, more than the box can fit, so I would like to make the label scroll automatically from the right to the left and make appear and disappear the letters who don't fit in the box. For now, I've created two lists to make a visible list and a waiting list, and I transfer letters from one to other, but the result is not fluid, smooth at all.

```
 private async void StartAnimation3()
    {
        List<char> firstQueue = new List<char>();
        List<char> secondQueue = new List<char>();
        string texteComplet = "Température bureau 20°C - 15000 lumens - Volets a 80%             ";

        foreach (char s in texteComplet)
        {
            secondQueue.Add(s);
        }

        while (true)
        {
            if (secondQueue.Count < BoxLabel.WidthRequest / 6)
            {

                if (secondQueue.Count != 0)
                {
                    char s = secondQueue[0];
                    secondQueue.RemoveAt(0);
                    firstQueue.Add(s);
                    await Task.Delay(50);
                }


                if (firstQueue.Count != 0)
                {
                    char s = firstQueue[0];
                    firstQueue.RemoveAt(0);
                    secondQueue.Add(s);
                    await Task.Delay(50);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                char s = secondQueue[0];
                secondQueue.RemoveAt(0);
                firstQueue.Add(s);
                await Task.Delay(50);
            }


            metroLabel.Text = String.Join("", secondQueue.ToArray());
            Console.WriteLine(metroLabel.Text);


        }

    }
```

I also try to make it work the TranslationX which work perfectly for the first scroll but when I try to make disappear the letters with a Substring, the same problem shows off, and the result is not smooth (saccadement). I think it's not a good idea to use both method at the same time, but I put that here if you have ideas. (the number 6 is approximately the number of pixels per letters)

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
     metroLabel.TranslationX -= 1;
     await Task.Delay(20);
}
```

Comment: You may also refer to this SO issue : [How to make Label text scroll automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57237615/how-to-make-label-text-scroll-automatically).